# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 background agent

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Silverlight 8.1 app in c#. I want to use some of the old phone APIs inside my background periodic task, so I can't use the new IBackgroundTask RT interface.

I created an old style Background agent with OnInvoke override then registered as before in WMAppManifest.xml: `<ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="BackgroundAgent" Source="BackgroundAgent" Type="BackgroundAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
      </ExtendedTask>`

Where BackgroundAgent is my background agent library and ScheduledAgent is my class.

I have enabled Toast notifications for the app in the Package.appxmanifest. My notification system is WNS (in WMAppManifest).

I am trying to launch the task in the old school way:

```
BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
  var periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find("BackgroundTask");

  if (periodicTask != null)
  {
    ScheduledActionService.Remove("BackgroundTask");
  }

  periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("BackgroundTask");
  (periodicTask as ScheduledTask).Description = "Hello, world.";
  ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);

  ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("BackgroundTask", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

Inside the OnNavigatedTo method of my MainPage.xaml.cs.

I can see this code run.

However, I never see any code run inside my background agent - it is supposed to send me a toast (I tried both with the ShellToast and the new ToastNotificationManager for xml-based toasts) and make a http call - both of which don't happen.

I watched the Build™ video where they mentioned that background agents should be fully supported in Silverlight 8.1 apps.

I can also confirm that my app appears as 'allowed' inside the battery Saver settings, which indicates that the background agent was registered with the os.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you update the answer with full solution, so that it will help others..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to have a background task of type "System event" with entry point "AgHost.BackgroundTask" in the Package.appxmanifest. That's what's hosting the SL background agent in WP8.1 SL apps. If you don't have this task in the manifest file, add it yourself and see it fixes your problem.

**Update**

From my experience the "System event" type should work, but zaitsman says that he needed to use "Timer", so if the first one does not work for you - try the other.

**Update 2**

In other words, you need to have this:

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
        <Task Type="timer" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

inside the Application tag of the **Package.appxmanifest** file (not to be confused with WMAppManifest.xml) of your WP 8.1 SL app.

Comment: I added that like this:
<Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>

However, my task still doesn't not run..

Comment: you were almost right - you need to also specify the trigger as 'timer' and it works.

Comment: @zaitsman Hmm, that is strange. I tested it with System event and it was working fine for me. I'll put a note in my answer about that.

Comment: it only really worked when I put both in; i didn't mind that, i was just glad it finally worked.

Comment: @yasen pls add code too, how to add timer and rest of the code. it would be much better.

Comment: @loop I added the code that I was talking about. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @yasen pls check :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933884/background-agents-in-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight#26933884

Comment: @zaitsman, do you have a trigger for your WNS notification feature? If yes, EntryPoint need to be modified to the trigger's entry, and this way, old style Background agent will not work again.

Comment: @sunjinbo this app had no push notifications feature.