# Background Agents in Windows phone 8.1 (Silverlight )

Tags: c#, silverlight, scheduled-tasks, windows-phone-8.1

I am following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx) for implementing the ScheduledAgent in WP 8.1 Silverlight.

Steps :-

Edited `WMAppManifest.xaml` :

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="/View/StartPage.xaml" />
  <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="ScheduledTaskAgent2" Source="ScheduledTaskAgent2" Type="ScheduledTaskAgent2.ScheduledAgent" />
  </ExtendedTask>
</Tasks>
```

Added new ScheduledAgent project with targeted version 8.1. : 
[image]

Now my ScheduledAgent Class

```
#define DEBUG_AGENT
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace ScheduledTaskAgent2
{
    public class ScheduledAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
    {

         protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
         { 

#if DEBUG_AGENT
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
            NotifyComplete();         

          }
    }
}
```

**My code to start the agent**

```
public const string PeriodicTaskName = "ScheduledTaskAgent2";
private PeriodicTask _periodicTask;

    private void StartPeriodicAgent()
    {
        _isPeriodicTaskStarted = true;

        _periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(PeriodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;

        if (_periodicTask != null)
        {
            RemoveAgent(PeriodicTaskName);
        }

        _periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(PeriodicTaskName) {Description = "periodic task."};

        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Add(_periodicTask);

#if(DEBUG_AGENT)
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(PeriodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
         }
         catch (Exception exception){ }
    }         

    private static void RemoveAgent(string name)
    {
       try
       {
           ScheduledActionService.Remove(name);
       }
       catch (Exception){}
    }
```

Now this all that I have tried for the background agent. This is not invoking the `OnInvoke()` Method (at least in debug mode)

**Note** : I have added the Reference to ScheduledTaskAgent2 project also.

Has anybody implemented the ScheduleAgent in WP 8.1 (Silverlight)

Is it supported at all ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution This is the fully working solution just copy paste it. Can't get it from documentation directly though. Just Add this Extention in your `Package.appxmanifest` File. you can open it by `right click => viewcode` option.

```
 <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent"  />
        <Task Type="timer"/>
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
```

Comment: You saved our lives! We had the same problem here and we found that the EntryPoint was wrong. With this entry point, we are able to debug now. 
Thank you!